# Rescale x-axis of an Histogram with fixed bins

Tags: histograms

I produced an histogram using this simple code:

```
Histogram[{data}]
```

where data is a set of 100 values. The result was:
[image]

I now would like to "rescale" the x-asis in order to obtain something like this 
[image]

I tried with `Histogram[{data}, {{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048,4096}}]` but it didn´t work because in the x-axis there are still all bins, not only the one I want.

Do you have any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: For these particular bins why not just perform a `Histogram` using `Log[2,data]` ?

Comment: Why not `PlotRange-> {{x0,x1},All}` - that's separate from the bin range/width spec - ie, 2nd argument to `Histogram`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain bar heights using `HistogramList` with your bin specification, and use the result in `BarChart`:

```
data = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[2, 5], 1000];
binspec = {Prepend[2^Range[0, 13], 0]};
xlabels = Rotate[Style[#, 16, "Panel"], Pi/2] & /@ Append[binspec[[1, 2 ;; -2]], Infinity];

heights1 = HistogramList[data, binspec, "Count"][[2]];
BarChart[heights1, ChartLabels -> xlabels, BarSpacing -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
heights2 = HistogramList[data, binspec, "Probability"][[2]];
BarChart[heights2, ChartLabels -> xlabels, BarSpacing -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem @kglr !

Comment: @alphabeta, my pleasuer. Welcome to mma.se.